# How to convert a dataframe into datetime format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science, datetime-format

I have this dataframe:

```
3_21_19_59
1
4
22
25
28
31
34
37
.
.
.
.
```

It has 410 rows.

Here in `3_21_19_59`: `3` indicates month, `21` indicates date, `19` is hours and `59` is minutes. The numbers in the rows below that: `1`, `4`, `22`... are the seconds.

Now, I want to convert this dataframe into a datetime format like this:

```
2020-03-21 19:59:00
2020-03-21 19:59:01
2020-03-21 19:59:04
2020-03-21 19:59:22
2020-03-21 19:59:25
2020-03-21 19:59:28
...
...
...
```

and so on. And after 60 seconds, the minutes should be automatically incremented.  For example: If it's 64 seconds, it should be like `2020-03-21 19:60:04`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with format and `errors='coerce'` parameter, so missing values for not matched values. Then forward fillinf them for repating `datetimes`.

Then processing `seconds` - first convert to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), then to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and last add to datetimes:

```
print (df)
          col
0  3_21_19_59
1           1
2           4
3          22
4          25
5          28
6          31
7          34
8          37

d = pd.to_datetime('20_' + df['col'], format='%y_%m_%d_%H_%M', errors='coerce').ffill()
td = pd.to_numeric(df['col'],  errors='coerce').fillna(0)

df['col'] = d.add(pd.to_timedelta(td, unit='s'))
print (df)
                  col
0 2020-03-21 19:59:00
1 2020-03-21 19:59:01
2 2020-03-21 19:59:04
3 2020-03-21 19:59:22
4 2020-03-21 19:59:25
5 2020-03-21 19:59:28
6 2020-03-21 19:59:31
7 2020-03-21 19:59:34
8 2020-03-21 19:59:37
```